# Ionic/Angular: Bundle and load a dynamic external module that uses providers/components from the "core" of the app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, dynamic, webpack, systemjs

This post is to ask for guidance/ideas and, essentially, to know if what we want to do is possible using `Ionic` 3 and `Angular` 5. If you know a better place to ask for this, please let me know :)

We have an `Ionic` 1 app called `Moodle Mobile`(open source). This app allows you to connect to any server that has `Moodle` installed and configured to allow the app. You can think of it as Wordpress or Drupal: each institution has its own instance in its own server.

There are hundreds of `plugins` (in PHP) that can be installed into `Moodle` to enhance it, and some institutions develop their own plugins (usually private), so there's no way that our app supports everything. To improve this, we implemented what we call "remote addons".

Each Moodle plugin can include a ZIP file with its "remote addon". This zip file includes the `AngularJS` code to make that feature work in the mobile app, along with the `CSS`, images, lang files, etc. When the mobile app connects to a site, it downloads these remote addons and loads them dynamically using [ocLazyLoad](https://oclazyload.readme.io/). You can see an example of a remote addon [in here](https://github.com/markn86/moodle-mod_certificate/tree/master/mobile).

This has worked fine for us for almost 2 years. However, now we're migrating our app to use `Ionic` 3, and we don't know if we'll be able to support this. This feature (or a similar one) is a **must** for us, otherwise the institutions that already rely on this system will see how some features stop working.

For those of you who don't know, `Ionic` uses `AOT` compiler, and the JS code is bundled using `webpack`.

I've been investigating how to dynamically load external modules in `Angular`. I've seen that some posts and pages suggest using `SystemJS` for this, so that was my first try. However, the examples I found were always isolated modules, and that isn't our case. We want the remote addons to be able to inject and use providers and components from the app (that is, from outside of the addon).

I tried to bundle a module using `webpack` and `UMD` format, but the generated file included a lot of code from `Angular`, `Ionic` and my app. I guess `webpack` iterates over all the dependencies and includes them in the same file, so I ended up with a file with 150.000 lines. Of course, that isn't feasible for us. Maybe I'm doing something wrong when packaging? I used the `Ionic` build process as an example. Is it possible to include only the code from the module in the bundle but still use providers from outside of it?

We reached a stalemate at this point, so we started to think in alternatives. One of them would be to program the remote addons using plain Javascript, and our app should expose an API to provide access to the main providers and features. However, this wouldn't allow them to create custom components and directives, right?

Is there any way to achieve what we need? Can you think of an alternative way to support these external plugins without having to include all the code in the app itself?

Thank you!